# Can we work with friction and rotation of rigid bodies using General Relativity instead of Energy conservations and Newtonian Mechanics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, rotational-dynamics, energy-conservation, friction

Since general relativity is a theory of gravity and it explains many mysteries, Can it solve the Rotational and friction problems instead of using the Newtonian way of solving them? I'm just curious to know the answer to whether it is possible or not. I know that it is going to be a bit of a calculation to actually apply it but just wanted to know whether it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

No, General Relativity is incompatible with extended rigid bodies. Special Relativity is also incompatible with extended rigid bodies. Friction and rotation are both fine, although they tend to be more complicated than necessary in relativity.

Comment: Thank you very much :)